# jQuery code function aliases

Tags: javascript, jquery

I was looking through the jQuery core code and noticed the following:

```
var core_indexOf = Array.prototype.indexOf, 
    core_toString = Object.prototype.toString
```

Later the usage of these was:

```
core_indexOf.call(arr, elem, i); 

core_toString.call(obj);
```

Is this merely just aliasing the function names or is there a performance benefit of using this technique?

Comment: If anything it's a minification benefit, thus reducing the size of the library when minified.